# Does "Class myclass = Class()" waste resources?

Tags: c++, resources, constructor

I have a class:

```
class Cat {
   Cat();
   Tail longTail;
}
```

I am not sure about a proper way to write constructor for it. I don't want to make longTail a pointer for non-related reason.

```
Cat::Cat() : longTail(length) {...}
```

That one doesn't fit because length is calculated in constructor, based on static members values at the moment of creation; (Poor practices upstream);

---

**The question is**

```
Cat::Cat() 
{
   int length;
   ...
   longTail = Tail(length);
}
```

How many times does creation and copying of *Tail* objects happen? They are CPU-expensive to both create and copy, and I need thousands of cats. It seems to me, this constructor first creates a default *Tail* object in *longTail*, after that it creates noname Tail object on the right of assignment, then runs operator= on *longTail* and noname *Tail*. Am I right? If yes, how should I write it instead to preserve CPU? I repeat: *longTail* needs a parameter, that is calculated in the constructor, and I can't edit *Tail* class.

Comment: Have you actually tested that efficiency is a problem?

Comment: Each Tail has a float array[80][80] and I'm writing for embedded. Yes, it IS a problem to sqeeze out every CPU cycle of parts I may edit;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your second version your `Tail`-object will be default-initialized before the body of the constructor is run. In the body you create a second `Tail`-object and assign it to the first one.

To enable correct construction in the initializer-list, you could wrap the computation of the parameters in a static member-function (since, as you said, it only depends in static members):

```
class Cat {
public:
    Cat() : longTail(calculateLength()) {...} 

private:
    static int calculateLength() {}
```

Comment: `Cat::Cat()` inside the class ?

Comment: @Nawaz: Copy-paste-mistake - fixed.

Comment: @curiousguy: Thanks, fixed. You should know that you can fix things like typos yourself.

Comment: @BjörnPollex "_You should know that you can fix things like typos yourself_" there is this "edit" button, but then it says "_Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary._" and it did not seem _absolutely_ necessary.

Comment: I really dislike this style where you have to move code that is naturally part of your constructor to an axillary function (here `calculateLength()`), only in order to use the constructor-init-list. (But in this case, it is apparently unavoidable.) To me, it shows why designs where a parameter can only be set at construction should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to me, this constructor first creates a default Tail object in longTail, after that it creates noname Tail object on the right of assignment, then runs operator= on longTail and noname Tail. Am I right?

Yes.

> If yes, how should I write it instead to preserve CPU?

Possible alternative: do not assign to `longTail`, fill `longTail` in place:

```
longTail.resize (length);
// or
longTail.reserve (length);
longTail.append (x).
```

Do you have realistic data sets to test your code?

Did you tried to profile your code?

Comment: You assume that `Tail` has methods `resize`, `reserve` and `append` - how so?

Comment: Exactly that is the problem. Length is set only in constructor and I may not edit the Tail class any way.

Comment: And Cat may not contain pointers dure to some guys' brilliant idea to do memory encryption in 'new' operator.

Comment: @BjörnPollex The OP provided very few information in his question about `Tail`; I assume it was `vector`-like.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino "_Length is set only in constructor_" Oh, I see. I did not get the "only in constructor part" at first. "_And Cat may not contain pointers_" so you cannot even have a fast `swap` function. "_some guys' brilliant idea to do **memory encryption** in 'new' operator_" WTF???!!!

Comment: @curiousguy I'm pretty sure that was an application of sarcasm. He suspects that OP's reasons for not using a pointer for the `Tail` are not very solid.

Comment: Yeah, it was a strange design, but I have to conform. Modified vectors and overloaded 'new' keep my objects encrypted even in memory, until I request them into stack. The idea is that even if thief gets our device and freezes memory state somehow, she won't get much use. I am no cryptography man, and can't explain more. For me it is all dumb paranoia, especially on ARMv5.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino where is the encryption key stored?

Comment: @curiousguy I think on a parent device, available by wireless. Device takes key, unencrypts current layer, does what it needs, forgets key, advances to next layer, requests next key.

Comment: The fact is that some getters in "Tail" classes take minutes to return, obviously waiting for thier key.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino Strange design.